# In Symmetric encryption where Alice and Bob message each other, how can both decrypt the same data?

Tags: encryption, public-key, symmetric

I first posted this question on StackOverflow but they told me it belongs here instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856486/in-symmetric-encryption-where-alice-and-bob-message-each-other-how-can-both-dec

I am building a messaging app where one client can message another.

There will be 2 clients - Alice and Bob. Alice needs to be able to send an encrypted message to Bob and vice versa.

These encrypted messages will need to be stored on a server so that Alice and Bob apps can retrieve them. However, only Alice and Bob apps should be able to decrypt the messages.

**IMPORTANT: Both Alice and Bob should be able to decrypt all messages between each other. Also neither Alice, nor Bob should be storing decrypted data on their devices. Both should be fetching the encrypted data from server, then decrypting it as needed.**

The server shouldn't be able to decrypt the data. Nor should a 3rd party Mallory be able to decrypt the data between Alice and Bob. The server shouldn't have access to any secret/private keys. The server should only store the sender, the receiver, and the encrypted content itself. The server should return the encrypted content to both as asked for.

I know that I shouldn't use asymmetric encryption for encrypting large quantities of data. This has been explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption

which states:

> Asymmetric encryption doesn’t require a shared secret. On the other hand, it’s computationally expensive and works only on small, discrete blocks of data. Therefore, it’s most suitable for small transfers when sender and receiver have no established relationship.

> Symmetric encryption is good for bulk data transfer because it’s computationally efficient and operates on streams of data. But it works only when the transmitter and the receiver share a secret key. So you typically rely on some other technique, such as asymmetric encryption or the Diffie-Hellman key exchange, to share a key and establish a session.

> When the sender and receiver share a single, secret key, they can perform symmetric encryption, in which the same key both encrypts and decrypts the message. Even though the operations in this case are computationally efficient, initially sharing the key poses its own challenge. For that reason, you’ll usually want to use another method, such as asymmetric encryption, to exchange a symmetric key at the time you begin communicating.

> On the encryption side, instead of simply padding and encoding the given block of data with the key, the SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(*:*:*:*:) function first generates a random Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) session key. It uses this key to encrypt the input data, and then RSA encrypts the AES key using the input public key you provide. It finally assembles the RSA encrypted session key, the AES encrypted data, and a 16-byte AES-GCM tag into a block of data that it returns to you. On the decryption side, the process is reversed. The function decrypts the AES session key using the private key you provide as input and then uses that to decrypt the data.

It's the last few sentences here which I am having problems with. It explains how in order for Alice to send encrypted data to Bob, Alice can use the `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` to generate a random AES session key to encrypt the data, and RSA encrypts this random AES session key using Bob's public key. On Bob's side, Bob decrypts and gets this random AES session key using his private key and then uses it to decrypt the data.

This allows Bob to get the decrypted data which Alice sent.

1. However, how would Alice decrypt this same data? I don't want Alice to be storing the decrypted data before sending it. The encrypted data should only be stored on server and both Alice and Bob should fetch it from there, and decrypt it.
2. Is my thinking flawed? Is there some other way I can achieve this?

One of the answers on that original StackOverflow post suggested this:

> You can't rely on an AES session key in your scenario as that key is ephemeral. The party that imitates the conversation (say Alice) need to explicitly generate a symmetric key and store it securely (Call it "AliceandBob"). You can then use asymmetric encryption to share this key with Bob (who also stores it as "AliceandBob"). Then this symmetric key is used to encrypt all communications between the pair.

This is kind of what I was thinking I might need to do.

3. Is it okay then for whosoever public key is "first" in ascending order to generate this symmetric key, store it, and send it to other using asymmetric encryption?
4. Or can I do something like both parties create a symmetric key and send it to other along with a timestamp and then whosever timestamp is 1st becomes the symmetric key to be used for encrypting all future communications?

I feel a bit like I am reinventing a wheel. Isn't this type of exchange fairly common use case in messaging apps and thus documented somewhere? I tried researching but there's too many irrelevant articles.

**EDIT:**

I found this solution on iOS which seems helpful:

https://gist.github.com/mehmeteminkartal/e2d1ee56526dc032b7257aef80c40d16

Apple's doc regarding this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret

They say:

> Generate a shared secret by calling your private key’s sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(publicKeyShare:) method with the public key from another party. **The other party computes the same secret by passing your public key to the the equivalent method on their own private key.** The shared secret isn’t suitable as a symmetric cryptographic key (SymmetricKey) by itself. However, you use it to generate a key by calling either the hkdfDerivedSymmetricKey(using:salt:sharedInfo:outputByteCount:) or x963DerivedSymmetricKey(using:sharedInfo:outputByteCount:) method of the shared secret. **After the other party does the same, then you both share a symmetric key suitable for** creating a message authentication code like HMAC, **or for opening and closing a sealed box with a cipher like ChaChaPoly or AES.**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret/x963derivedsymmetrickey(using:sharedinfo:outputbytecount:)

Comment: Have you ever considered investigating the signal protocol?

Comment: Check out how 'hybrid encryption' works. In brief: there you have a symmetric contents encryption key (CEK) and one to many asymmetric key encryption keys (KEK). You encrypt the contents using the CEK, then you encrypt the CEK with the (public) KEK of all the users that should be able to read the contents, and attach the encrypted CEKs to the contents

Comment: What is the motivation for not keeping data on clients? In your scenario, Alice generated the symmetric encryption key. So she can just keep it and use it to decrypt data whenever she fetches the data from the server. In any case, both, Bob and Alice needs to keep some secret data around, for AES or RSA (same goes even if using Diffie-Hellman). There are advanced protocols to reduce the consequence of compromise, but that seems unnecessary here. As said above, I would also suggest investigating existing protocols like signal.

Comment: Key agreement is a different way of deriving the data keys. I'm wondering a bit how you're going to store the symmetric keys if you want to decrypt the data at a later time. I'm not saying that this is impossible, but it has significantly different implications w.r.t. security of the scheme.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I will be storing the keys in the iOS Keychain. That's what Apple recommends.

Comment: Right, but are you going to store one key per participant or even message in there? Because if you're going to store the symmetric keys then that's what it would come down to. Just storing one or two private keys may be more efficient.

Comment: It would be one key per participant. Alice will store Bob's public key and the corresponding shared symmetric key to be used for encrypting all communication. Bob will store Alice's public key and the same shared symmetric key to be used for encrypting all communication. That link at the bottom of my post seems to show me how both Alice and Bob can come up with the same symmetric key.

Comment: Well, it certainly **can** work. Tips: Don't forget to describe your protocol, add a security section and add some kind of versioning to it.